# Laravel Blade pass array data to multiple extends

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've searched for this on internet alot, but wasnt able to find answers. I'm using Laravel 5 and I've little issue with blade templating as in my project I need sometime to do multiple extends and I need to pass all data from one layout to all master layouts "extends"

Nested page example :

```
@extends('layouts.full', ['var' => 'key'])

@section('page')
   page content here
@stop
```

layouts/full.blade.php example

```
@extends('app', ['need to pass same data here too'])

@section('content')
   @yield('page')
@stop
```

and app.blade.php is just main html stuff

And I wanted to ask is there possibility to pass same vars without setting global variable like?

```
@extends('layouts.full', $data = [])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you : 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#service-injection

Answer (score 0):

to pass multiple variables, use an array:

```
@extends('layouts.full', [ 'data' => ['var' => 'key'] ])
```

as for multiple extensions, maybe just use include statements in layouts.full :

```
@include('header')
@section('content')
    @yield('page')
@stop
@include('footer')
```